# Bluetooth isEnabled() fails

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use this code to start bluetooth:

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(btAdapter == null)
   returns; /no bluetooth
if(btAdapter.isEnabled() == false)
{  Toast("Bluetooth off. Starting it...");
   if(btAdapter.enable() == false)
      Toast("Error enabling bluetooth.");
}
```

It should be very simple. Just gets and adapter and if it is not enabled then I start it.

The problem is that isEnabled() returns false when bluetooth is actualy ON (it should return true) And calling to enable() returns false so it shows "Error enabling bluetooth." I guess because it was already ON. After that my bluetooth symbols (in the status bar) is gone.
Any hint?

Of course I have the permissions.

Comment: Please include the logcat output in your question.

Comment: I can just use it in real phone. My emulator don't have bluetooth

Comment: If you cannot use logcat with your phone you should solve that problem first. Did you enable USB debugging on the phone? Which phone do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea I could connect my phone (Samsung galaxy scl) to Eclipse and debug it.
Let me work on it and I would let you know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry... Everything works fine. The problem was in a different place. I am embarresed. Thanks anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: If you found a solution on your own, please provide it as an answer and accept it here. If you don't, this question will linger around here as unanswered forever. Please do not delete the question as the people who tried to help would loose their reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enable Bluetooth without the user's confirmation. You need to do it like this,

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
    // Device supports Bluetooth

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Bluetooth isn't enabled, so enable it.
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

A dialog will appear requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth, as shown below.

[image]

If the user responds "Yes," the system will begin to enable Bluetooth and focus will return to your application once the process completes (or fails).

Comment: I don't have the problem enabling it. I have the problem asking for the state. IsEnabled() always returns false. If it is correct (bluetooth is off) I am able to turnit on with Enable() and works!!.
But if it is ON already, isEnable() returns false (error) and my app uses enable(). Obviously this fails because it was already on. Thanks.

Comment: sorry... Everything works fine. The problem was in a different place. I am embarresed. Thanks anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: If the adapter instance is null then still "Device supports Bluetooth"? It should be actually Device doesn't support bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

ensure you have the permissions correct in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: tried the exact same code above and it works fine (with permissions of course). Are you using trying it on the emulator? The only way to help is by seeing the LogCat output

Comment: Yes, sometimes it works for me too. I notice it fails when I launch the activity from a threaf. Could it be?

Comment: Please rephrase. What do you mean by "Launch Activity from a Thread"?

Comment: ok. I know I can only enable bluetooth using Enable() without user iteration from an activity. And it works fine normally. But I have a running thread that activates other things like ring volume, notification volume, wallpaper picture, ... and bluetooth. For BT I need to start that activity I talked before and there is where the problem starts: isEnable() allways returns false (BT is Off even when it is On).

Comment: Check how they have done it in the Android Sample named `Bluetooth Chat`. I wasn't able to past the code in the `onStart()` method here. Am sure that will help you see where and when it is appropriate to enable Bluetooth

Comment: sorry... Everything works fine. The problem was in a different place. I am embarresed. Thanks anyway for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

To check Bluetooth state, ON programmatically:

1. Add Following Permission : -

   `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`
2. Use Following Function For Enable BLUETOOTH:-

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

private void turnOn() {

   if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new 
        Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBtIntent);
    }

}
```